# Client-Side validation not working in asp.net .net framework 4.5.2

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code works fine in 4.0 framework but not in 4.5. The form does not raise any error whenth invalid value is typed in textbox that goes against the regex defined. For e.g the txtFees should not allow any alpha characters. But form does not raise any errors any is successfully submitted.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
MasterPageFile="~/PresentationLayer/MasterPage.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PackagesAdd.aspx.cs"
Inherits="PresentationLayer_PackagesAdd" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"
runat="Server">
    <head>

    <script src="../src/js/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../production/css/sweetalert.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function JSalert(x) {
            swal(x);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2>
                Add Packages </h2>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                    aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
            <br />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                   Package Name <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPackageName" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" 
ValidationGroup="Add"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPackageName"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Input" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 -.]{1,}$"
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                   Fees
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFees" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
ValidationGroup="Add"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="txtFees"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Input" ValidationExpression="^[0-9.]{1,}$"
                        SetFocusOnError="True" EnableClientScript="true" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ln_solid">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="Add"
CausesValidation="true"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </asp:Content>
```

Comment: When you say it works and there is no error, what is actually happening then and where should it be happening. A code dump like this isnt that useful for us. 

Please edit the question to detail, who, what, where, when, why and how.

Comment: Do you have any errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: It works fine when project is developed on vs 2010 but not working vs2015. By not working I mean that the page is not raising any validation error in browser.. Not it does not give any error in console

Comment: what about when you run it in IIS and not IIS Express or in debug mode in VS2010 and 2015?

Comment: Also, when did you see the fault? was it when you changed your target framework or when you changed your vs environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below block of code to resolve your issue.

//Error ValidationGroup.

you should add ValidationGroup name in Validation control.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
MasterPageFile="~/PresentationLayer/MasterPage.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PackagesAdd.aspx.cs"
Inherits="PresentationLayer_PackagesAdd" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"
runat="Server">
    <head>

    <script src="../src/js/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../production/css/sweetalert.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function JSalert(x) {
            swal(x);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2>
                Add Packages </h2>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                    aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
            <br />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                   Package Name <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPackageName" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPackageName" ValidationGroup="Add"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Input" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 -.]{1,}$"
                        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                   Fees
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFees" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="txtFees" ValidationGroup="Add"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Input" ValidationExpression="^[0-9.]{1,}$"
                        SetFocusOnError="True" EnableClientScript="true" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ln_solid">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="Add"
CausesValidation="true"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Glad it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using  setting UnobtrusiveValidationMode to none

`protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
}`